# session for multiple devices

Tags: session, cookies, e-commerce, cart

I am trying to build an ecommerce site.for the cart functionality I want to alive my cart for multiple devices.For example if I create an account and add some product to my cart using my mobile browser,after that if I use the same account to my pc browser I should see the cart with those product I added using my mobile browser.I donno how to do that or what's the method,can you please help me??

Answer (score 0):

**My Preferred Approach**
In order to do this, you'll want to create or leverage some sort of profile data source. For example, if you're using a database, you likely have a `Users` table with a record for each customer.  I'd suggest adding a new related table that might look something like this to begin with...

Potential Table Name: `UserData`

- UserID (FK)
- DataName (string)
- DataValue (string)

So, after logging in, the visitor might add something to their cart.  When this happens, you'd have a `CartID` to work with and then add a record to that table with their `UserID` and it might look like this in T-SQL.

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserData] ([UserID],[DataName],[DataValue]) 
VALUES (12345, 'CartID', 'd501e3de-350c-4c20-92c8-8e71445e1774');
```

Now, when they log in again anywhere, you'd just query for that `UserID` to find out if they have a cart pending.  If they do, load it up.  Just remember to clear that value on checkout.

The beauty of this solution is that you can repurpose it for all kinds of other things.

**An Alternative Approach**
Just query your `Cart` table, assuming in your solution you're storing carts before checkout is completed.  Find the most recent instance of a cart matching their `UserID` that hasn't been completed.